# iOS Restkit needNewBodyStream called

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I perform request to server via Restkit. It is worked well, but sometimes that method is called:

```
- (NSInputStream *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection needNewBodyStream:(NSURLRequest *)request
{
    RKResponseIgnoreDelegateIfCancelled(nil);
    RKLogWarning(@"RestKit was asked to retransmit a new body stream for a request. Possible connection error or authentication challenge?");
    return nil;
}
```

and I dont receive response from server.

Why is it called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `NSURLConnection` performs a POST, PUT or PATCH request with a data source specified as a `NSInputStream` via NSMutableRequest's `setHTTPBodyStream:` method, it will open the stream and read bytes from it to send the data to the server.

In most cases this will work, since this request is actually that request the server is expecting.

There are situations though, where the server cannot process this POST request immediately, for example when the server requires an authentication. In order to accomplish authentication, the server sends a "redirect response" to the client - and thereby ignoring the so far received bytes which is the partial POST data already send from the client. The client is required to authenticate through sending credentials, and then subsequently sending the original request again form start.

Now, `NSStream` cannot be "rewinded". That means, once a client has opened a stream and read bytes from it and it's current position has been moved on, one cannot set the position to the start. Conceptually, it's a "forward iterator". In order to start from the beginning, the `NSStream` must be re-created, opened and read again. Unfortunately, the `NSURLRequest` cannot handle this since it doesn't know where the stream did come from and how to create it.

When the `NSURLConnection` needs to "re-start" the body data stream set in the request, `NSURLConnection` sends the message `connection:needNewBodyStream:`.

The delegate needs to provide a newly created stream, likely just in the same way as the first has been created, and assign it the `NSURLRequest` via `setHTTPBodyStream:`.

Comment: I am also enountering same problem, so please can you guide what should i do in my code to solve this problem?

Comment: @AadilAli You need to implement `connection:needNewBodyStream:`. The method should create and return a new `NSStream` object in the same way you created it for the initial request.